# How to replace a string after character in jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml

How to replace a string after character in jquery?
I have the following xml string. It can be well form and not well form at certain time. so I cannot use jquery xml parser. What I want to do is take out `ExtnLockID='123456'` and replace with `ExtnLockID='some string'`. The value (123456) of ExtnLockID is dynamic and not 123456 all the time.

```
<myOr>
    <Extn ExtnLockID='123456' something="here"/>
    <ship cut='0001' any='2' orig='1' node='1'>
        <Extn type='RELEASE' ref='xey-15504'>
            <home>
                <howdy mesg='5a2a68a0-9ea0-4443-9d96-7923e42d52c6'/>
            </home>
        </Extn>
        <bab>
            <someone docum='0001' home='SL' class='GOOD' qua='1.000000' no='0'>
                <XEX acot='121152' dotz='RELEASE'/>
            </someone>
        </bab>
    </ship>
</myOr>
```

The result should be:

```
<myOr>
        <Extn ExtnLockID='some string' something="here"/>
        <ship cut='0001' any='2' orig='1' node='1'>
            <Extn type='RELEASE' ref='xey-15504'>
                <home>
                    <howdy mesg='5a2a68a0-9ea0-4443-9d96-7923e42d52c6'/>
                </home>
            </Extn>
            <bab>
                <someone docum='0001' home='SL' class='GOOD' qua='1.000000' no='0'>
                    <XEX acot='121152' dotz='RELEASE'/>
                </someone>
            </bab>
        </ship>
    </myOr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
var newValue = "some string";
xml = xml.replace(/(ExtnLockID=')([^']*)(')/, "$1"+newValue+"$3");
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy! what if it has just <Extn /> and I want to make it add  ExtnLockID='some string' as an attribute of Extn element. the result should be <Extn ExtnLockID='some string' something='here'/>

Comment: @onelazyguy You can then define a second replacement from `/<Extn\s*\/>/` to your string.

Comment: var xml = editable_Xml.replace(/(ExtnLockID=')([^']*)'/, "$1"+newLockId+"'").replace(/<Extn\s*\/>/);
console.log("new xml is: " + xml); the log show it as undefined, can you give me the full code example?

Comment: thanks dystroy, but not quite. sometimes <Extn ExtnLockID='xxxxyyy' something="here"/> has the ExtnLockID but sometimes it might not have ExtnLockID. It might have just <Extn something="here"/> or <Extn />. so I just want two regexp so that if I check and the xml does not have ExtnLockID then use your first regexp to put the ExtnLockID in there and if the xml has ExtnLockID and replace its value with a new value. Thanks for helping me

Comment: anyone else have any input into this?

Answer (score -1):

```
var $xml = $(xml),
    $elem = $xml.find('[ExtnLockID]'),
    oldvalue = $elem.attr('ExtnLockID');
$elem.attr('somestring'); // update value
```

Comment: *"not well form at certain time. so I cannot use jquery xml parser"*